# rvest several text lines at the same time

Tags: r, rvest

I am scraping Udemy courses, and I would like to scrape the incentives on the right:

[image]

The css of all of them is `.incentives__text`.

This is de url:

```
  url <- read_html("https://www.udemy.com/linux-linux-security-masterclass-3-in-1/")

  incentives <- list()

  incentives <- url %>%
            html_nodes(".incentives__item") %>% # isloate the text
            html_text() # get the text
```

This onlye scrapes the first line, but I would like to scrape all the incentives at once. How can I do it?

Comment: What is the purpose of `incentives <- list()`?

Comment: Your code works well for me.

Comment: Your code works for me as well. It returns string vector of 5.

Comment: _"You may not scrape, spider, use a robot, or use other automated means of any kind to access the Services"_ / https://www.udemy.com/terms/